# spring-data-mongodb converters on embedded documents doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, converters, spring-data-mongodb

I need to **read** documents (**ParentDocument**) containing a list of beans (**ChildDocument**). And these beans, **i need to convert only a specific field** (**content**) to change the value.
It is only for reading mongoDb and load the bean, not to store in mongodb the modification.

For example:

```
@Document(collection = "parent")
  class ParentDocument {

    @Id
    String id;

    List<ChildDocument> children;
 }

  @Document
  class ChildDocument {

    @Id
    String id;

    // Modify the content reading in the database before storing the result in the java bean
    String content;
 }
```

I try to use converter on ChildDocument, but it doesn't work because converters are not used for embedded documents like ChildDocument (I think?).

**Someone can help me and have a clean solution to do this?**

Thanks

Comment: Can you show, what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was:

- Create document converter for father and son
- Register a converter for father
- In the Convert method of the father, the son converter must be instantiated as the argument only source necessary for the child
- Assign the response to parent document instantiated inside the converter father

Well, all you need is to convert the parent document that triggers the conversion of the child.

See you soon...